# How to add url deeplink in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

How can I add deeplink (url like https://www.example.com) in iOS using swift.

The scheme in plist is not working if I enter url in it.

You can check the screenshot of plist attached.
[image]

Comment: There are lots of tutorial available on internet, Please first try to search and then post questions here. BTW, Follow link for your questions: http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: @Paul All the tutorials are for deeplink like this twitter://post?message=using%20  but I need to implement deeplink for a URL like https://www.example.com

Comment: a deep link starts with the appName://

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are attempting to register your app for the URI scheme `https` which Apple has already reserved for Safari, therefore you will not be able to use it.

### Option 1: Custom URI Scheme

You must come up with a custom URI scheme like `customURI://www.domain.com`

**Downside**: If a user clicks on this link without the app installed. iOS will show that user and error.

### Option 2:Universal Links

Apple launched [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS 9 to enable developers to associate their `http` link with their app. This requires you to host your own AASA file on your domain so that your domain becomes associated with your app ID.

### Option 3: Branch.io

[Branch](https://branch.io) will actually bundle up Universal Links and URI schemes and use them appropriately when necessary. They also perform [deferred deep linking](https://blog.branch.io/deferred-deep-linking-with-device-snapshotting/). They'll host your AASA file for you, but your app domain will have to be either `https://*.app.link` or some dedicated subdomain of a domain that you own.

Answer (score 0):

only to be precise:

If you need more docs about in Apple docs, use the CORRECT name for the technology.

If You use  url starting with a schema different from http (for example fb:// for FB) is not a LINK, is a "custom" url.

Anyway use: custom url and see at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html